# I'm traveling from LA to Bali, with a 4 hour layover in Taiwan. Would I need to go through customs in Taipei?

Tags: transit, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, taipei

Additionally, do I need to hold any special visas upon entry to Bali? Or am I granted one upon entry?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: United States of America

Comment: What airlines are you flying, and are your flights on a single ticket?

Comment: T1 and T2 airside is linked. No custom and immigration check is needed if you don't exit the airside (Except PRC resident and the case of Jpatokal)

Comment: US citizens do not require visa to enter Indonesia and are allowed to stay in the country for up to 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

No, Taipei airport has airside transit, so you do not need to go through customs in Taiwan, assuming you have a single ticket.

Also for Bali you'll be getting a **free** Indonesian visa now, as long as you're leaving Indonesia through Bali or other approved airports. Visas are free since mid-March 2016 (<s>as usual, they made them free two days after I entered Indonesia :(</s>)